# Using jquery, can I get the X and Y offsets of a particular element?

Tags: jquery

Using jquery, can I get the X and Y offsets of a particular element?

Comment: -1 No where near enough details to be relevant

Answer (score 6):

Relative to what? Its parent? The document?

[CSS/position](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/position) gets the top and left position of an element relative to its offset parent.

[CSS/offset](http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset) gets the current offset of the first matched element, in pixels, relative to the document.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/offset.